# file retrieval in rails app using paperclip and fog-google

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, google-cloud-storage, fog

In a Rails 4 app, I am using Paperclip and the fog-google gem to store pictures in my Google Cloud Storage bucket.  Everything works great for file upload. The problem is that when I retrieve a bunch of photos to display, it is incredibly slow.  The requests take waaay longer than they should.  I believe the problem is that fog is authenticating each and every request so it takes a long time to retrieve a bunch of files. In my development environment, things are really snappy because the pictures are stored locally.  It is only in production that the requests are really slow.  The url of the stored file in the Google bucket is public, so I am wondering if there is away to tell fog not to authenticate on the GET requests.  Does anyone know how I can do this so that every single request for a file is not authenticated??

```
#config/environments/production.rb

Rails.application.configure do
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    storage: :fog,
    fog_credentials: {
      google_storage_access_key_id: ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_STORAGE_ID'),
      google_storage_secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_STORAGE_SECRET'),
      provider: 'Google' },
    fog_directory: '<bucket name>' }
end

#app/models/item.rb

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image
end

#migration

class AddAttachmentImageToItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :sitems do |t|
      t.attachment :image
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_attachment :items, :image
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried using the new JSON API that was added recently? It should be mostly backwards-compatible. To activate just remove the legacy credentials and add the standard ones in ('google-client-id', etc.) https://github.com/fog/fog-google/blob/master/examples/storage_json.rb

Comment: @John Hess I too am facing the same problem you mentioned. Did you found any solution to it using the interoperability credentials itself? Personally I feel Using the JSON API seems like more work compared to using the HMAC creds (i.e interoperability credentials).

Comment: @JiggneshhGohel No I did not find a solution for this. I am not sure which is better.  I can say that I have not had the easiest time working with Google's APIs. I wanted to avoid authentication altogether so I migrated all my photos to AWS S3 buckets.  It works very well with Paperclip.  Let me know if you have any more questions

Comment: I had the same problem and I manage to partially sorted it out [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40651880/1498118). On the last project I'm going to try Carrierwave with Google Storage and see if it's any better.