# Google Cloud Storage requests are slow using Paperclip and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, paperclip, google-cloud-storage

I have a Rails application that uses Google Cloud Storage for images. Each view has approximately 8 image and when a user tries to load the page it takes more than 5 seconds to complete because of requests to GCS.

Requests are made by Paperclip with the following config:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :fog,
  fog_credentials: {
    google_storage_access_key_id: myAccessKey,
    google_storage_secret_access_key: mySecretKey,
    provider: 'Google'
  },
  fog_public: true,
  fog_directory: 'mybucket'
}
```

In my view I call each image this way:

```
<%= image_tag myAsset.image.url %>
```

Is there any faster way to achieve the same result?

Lazy load seems to me a workaround rather then a solution, I'm I wrong?

Here New Relic infamous analysis (green belongs Google Cloud Storage requests)

[image]

Comment: How big is the GCS resource? Is it just one image? Is the bucket's class standard, DRA, or nearline?

Comment: Every view has around 8 images of approximately 300kb each. Then the bucket is a _standard_ one.

Comment: So if it takes 5 seconds to load the images, and there are 8 300kb images on the page, that's about 480kbps. There are plenty of Internet users whose Internet speed is limited to around that. Do you know how slow the user in question's Internet is?

Comment: I don't think I can get user's internet speed. Anyhow at this point lazy load *is the only solution* to speed up page load time, isn't it?

Comment: Alternatively, load smaller versions of the images first and lazy load the actual images.

Comment: As I said to @melgart I've found out that the slowness is due to Paperclip and the way it generate urls. You can find more here: github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2337

Answer (score 1):

are the images for a given request pulled every time from the backend? if so, use a cache for the images so you only take the time hit on the first request. possibly even start pulling images into a cache after user auth's in -- lazy loading like you suggested.

Comment: Hi @melgart, I've found out that the slowness is due to Paperclip and the way it  generate urls. You can find more here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2337

Comment: nice! thank you for bringing that knowledge back here where everyone can see your solution. you'll probably save someone hours of looking later.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say that this sorted everything out, but at least it speeds it up.

`fog_host` seems to avoid the network request.

```
# config/application.rb
module Parasite
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.paperclip_defaults = {
      fog_host: 'http://mybucektname.storage.googleapis.com',
      # ... other options
    }

  end
end
```

If you want to dig more check [the code](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/v5.1.0/lib/paperclip/storage/fog.rb#L137-L138) or this thread I opened on the [Paperclip Github Page](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/2337).